# Huge margin in form that I don't see in InfoPath designer?

Tags: infopath, custom-form, form, list-form

This is my first form design.  Below is a screenshot of InfoPath followed by a screenshot of the form dialog in Sharepoint using IE11.  I added an ugly background color to make it obvious what's going on.

[image]

[image]

I've tried everything I can find including the option "Use a custom layout width for this form template" and setting it to 400px wide manually.  I still can't get rid of the whitespace on the left.

Comment: I found this in the CSS: `#contentBox
{
margin-right:20px;margin-left:220px;
min-width:703px;}`  How can I edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a conflict with the Oslo template. If you switch to Seattle, it goes away.

I was able to work around it by editing the forms in Designer 2013. You'll want to make the same edit on each of displayifs.aspx, editifs.aspx, and newifs.aspx.

Find this section near the top:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span class="die">
        <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="LinkTitle" runat="server" id="ID_LinkTitle"/>
    </span>
</asp:Content>
```

Change it to this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span class="die">
        <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="LinkTitle" runat="server" id="ID_LinkTitle"/>
    </span>
    <style>
        #sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none;visibility:hidden; }
        #contentBox { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

update - The > was missing off the end

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

> On the View menu, click Manage Views.
>
> In the Views task pane, select the view whose margins you want to
>   modify, and then click View Properties.
>
> In the View Properties dialog box, click the Page Setup tab.
>
> Under Margins, select the options that you want.

Comment: I assume this menu is only for printing?  Regardless, it doesn't affect the dialog margins in any way.